# Firestore: How can I create a subcollection in Firestore without having to add a document already

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm on Android:
In the firestore console I am able to create a sub collection without having to add data (e.g. a document), but i can't figure out how to do it with the api.
for example

```
   db.collection(*colelctionName*)
            .document(*documentName*)
            .collection(*subCollectionName*)
```

Doesn't create the sub-collection and i need ot add:

```
.add(Object ...)
```

But this actually creates a document already in the sub-collection.
What i want to know if and how it is possible to create the (sub)collection without having to already add a document/data to that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Collections in Firestore only exist if there is a document or subcollection in them. It is not possible to create a completely empty collection.